# How to get Custom Profile Property to show in Edit Profile

Tags: dotnetnuke

We need to add some custom profile properties to user accounts. So we have gone through Site Settings and added the Custom Profile Properties and made sure they are visible to all.  What expect is that now a user can go to Edit Profile and those new custom profile properties can be set.  It doesnt happen. What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of DNN there are a few things that could be happening.

1. Be sure to clear the cache, and/or restart the application to ensure that the list is current
2. Check to see if your site is using anything for a custom profile module.  (Either customized registration form via Admin -> Site Settings -> User Accounts or possibly using Dynamic Registration or otherwise.)  If using a custom form you will need to update it as well